# nextflow `fromPath` not passing all files with *

Tags: nextflow

main.nf is

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

params.input = ''
tchan = Channel.fromFile(params.input)

tchan.println()
```

I have a.bam, b.bam and c.bam

I run:

```
nextflow run main.nf --input *bam
```

But it only prints `a.bam`

According to the [documentation](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#frompath), wildcard character it is interpreted as a glob path matcher

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Shell expands wildcards, try `ls *` vs  `ls "*"` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got it!

I should run:

```
nextflow run main.nf --input "*bam"
```

instead of

```
nextflow run main.nf --input *bam
```